# Minecraft Redstone detecting players standing on a block in a radius!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

So, basically, I need to make it so that if a player is standing on a block of black wool in a radius of 50 (from the contraption), it will kill them instantly. how is this possible, if at all?
 I can't get it to work so that it will execute the 'kill @a' part for the people standing on wool. I know how to do it with a set of co-ordinates, but the area I have chosen is very large, and would be much faster and efficient to use [r=50]

Comment: Have you made an attempt to solve this yourself?

Comment: Yes I have, but I can't get it to work so that it will execute the 'kill @a' part for the people standing on wool. I know how to do it with a set of co-ordinates, but the area I have chosen is very large, and would be much faster and efficient to use [r=50]

Comment: I'd recommend adding that into your question.

Comment: The problem is /kill does not work with command blocks so try `/tp [players] ~ ~-100 ~`  to tp them into the void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `execute detect` command will let you have people only execute another command if a certain block is detected:

```
execute @a[r=50] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ wool 15 kill @p[r=0]
```

Here, the block being detected is black wool relatively 1 below all players in a 50 block radius. If it is detected, the player runs a kill command that will target themselves.

Comment: Thank you, but now I need it to work with glowstone. I've tried: execute @a[r=100] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ glowstone kill @p[r=0] but it says "kill is not a valid number"

Comment: You need to pass one extra parameter, namely the metadata, to your command. It should then be `execute @a[r=100] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ glowstone 0 kill @p[r=0]` (0 because there is no metadata to be set).